# Return view to original position after animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I've made it so that when a user taps on a text field, the view shifts up slightly so that the fields are still visible while a user is typing. It works great, however sometimes after the keyboard is dismissed, instead of returning to its original position, the view slides down too far (leaving a small blank black bar at the top). Does anyone know how I can just restore the view back to its original position? Here's my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    _userField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    [_userField setDelegate:self];

    _passField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    [_passField setDelegate:self];


    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}


- (void)dismissKeyboard
{
    [_userField resignFirstResponder];
    [_passField resignFirstResponder];

}

-(void)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}

-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self animateTextField:textField up:YES];
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self animateTextField:textField up:NO];
}

    -(void)animateTextField:(UITextField*)textField up:(BOOL)up
    {
        const int movementDistance = -130; // tweak as needed
        const float movementDuration = 0.3f; // tweak as needed

        int movement = (up ? movementDistance : -movementDistance);

        [UIView beginAnimations: @"animateTextField" context: nil];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];
        self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
```

Comment: What's firing that method? Are you listening for keyboard notifications?

Comment: You are not using AutoLayout? (I don't, just wondering).
A full understanding of frames, ensuring your previous location was stored AFTER the view loaded (may change with animation), and Quartz 2D will let you figure out where that strange shift comes in. Need to see the other code for changing back, storing position, and autolayout used.

Comment: Hi @StephenJ, yes I'm using AutoLayout. I assume because my code is moving the view up by a specific distance, I simply need to move the view back down by the 130 after the keyboard is dismissed. Any idea what that might look like? See above code edits.

Comment: If autolayout is turned on, the constraint pass will override the frame. You do not have frames, they are illusions at best, unless you turn translatesAutoResizingMasks on...

Comment: @StephenJ So if I turn autoLayout off, the frame method will work? Assuming I don't want to turn autoLayout off in that window (which, I may have to do), how would I turn translatesAutoResizingMasks on? Sorry for the newb question, I'm new to that one...

Comment: I actually forgot, it's a one-line call though. Yes, your frame code will work once you turn off auto-layout.
In truth, autolayout just waits until your frames are set, then it calculates where stuff should be using first year Algebra, and resets it. That sentence will help more once you know animation. 
Erica Sadun's book on autolayout + the apple programming guide is what I use. PM me and I'll send my short note version of the bullet points, in a few hours that is..

Comment: @StephenJ So I turned off autoLayout, and I've still got the same issue :/

Comment: Alright. The problem isn't specifically your logic, it's your positioning code + apple. First, breakpoint or print the center OR frame before it moves, then after, then after it moves back. If they are all the same, your superviews moved. If they aren't the same, measure it and see if it matches any other view or change you added (or apple).

Comment: The way to solve all of this, is no joke, read the animations guide, core graphics guide, views guide, and view controller guide. They have everything that ever happens, (and events). It took me days, and I ignores stuff like printers or specifics, the overview will teach you about how things move around in iOS

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to work with the keyboard notifications instead.  That way, it would work even if you have more than one field, you will be able to animate the change along with the keyboard animation, and you will know exactly how much screen estate you are loosing due to the keyboard showing.

First, in your view controller, register and unregister for the notifications:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShowNotification:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHideNotification:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}
```

Then implements the two methods being called when the notifications are triggered:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShowNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:[notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue]];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:(UIViewAnimationCurve)[notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue]];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    CGRect keyboardFrame = [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    [self.mainView adjustContentWithKeyboardHeight:keyboardFrame.size.height];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)keyboardWillHideNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:[notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue]];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:(UIViewAnimationCurve)[notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue]];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [self.mainView adjustContentWithKeyboardHeight:0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Finally, implement a `adjustContentWithKeyboardHeight` public method in your view.  Since that method is called in a `UIView` animation, all the changes will be animated.

If you are moving the views directly (put them all in a container view that you will move), keep the original Y position in a private property, then subtract from that property the keyboardHeight minus the remaining space below your textField, and assign that back to that field (or set the frame to your liking):

```
    CGFloat offsetY = keyboardHeight - (CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds) - CGRectGetMaxY(self.containerView.frame));
    CGRect containerFrame = self.containerView.frame;
    containerFrame.origin.y = self.containerViewPositionY - offsetY;
    self.containerView.frame = containerFrame;
```